Limiting VM CPU usage via vSphere API
How can I limit how much CPU a VM can use from vSphere API?
I found this API, but it doesn't have an option for limit:
https://developer.broadcom.com/xapis/vsphere-automation-api/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/vm/hardware/cpu/patch/
What I want is something like this:

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!
